# SSIS - Error in transferring data from Sharepoint source to OLDB destination

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, oledb

I am getting this error when trying to transfer data. I am new at SSIS  but if you can help would be great.

```
[OLE DB Destination 1 [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".

[OLE DB Destination 1 [2]] Error: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "Comments" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT". The data flow column type is "DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION". The conversion from the OLE DB type of "DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN" to the destination column type of "DBTYPE_WVARCHAR" might not be supported by this provider.

[OLE DB Destination 1 [2]] Error: Cannot create an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: OLE DB Destination 1 failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202025.

Task Get Merchant Data failed
```

Comment: Can you show us what the source columns are?

Comment: Yeah SureSELECT [ID]
      ,[Status]
      ,[Store_No (LinkTitle)]
      ,[Merchant_No]
      ,[Comments]
      ,[Created]
      ,[Third_Party_Introduced_Customer]
  FROM [dbo].[tmp_Merchant
GO

Answer (score 1):

OK so the key part of the error is

```
"Comments" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT". The data flow column type is "DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION". The conversion from the OLE DB type of "DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN" to the destination column type of "DBTYPE_WVARCHAR"  might not be supported by this provider.
```

So you are trying to write to a TEXT column (NTEXT since this is unicode data).
Your source for comments has type `DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN` which it is saying it does not know how to convert to NTEXT resulting in your error.

The fix is to edit your source connection and to declare a datatype that can be converted, since it is currently set to unknown, I guess that you did not do this already.

So open the souce connection and edit the datatype of the comment column and choose the appropriate result. It is likely to be some form of NTEXT or WTEXT, that will convert to the NTEXT on import

Comment: Thanks Mike. I didn't knew at first how to do it but i played with a converter and then i took your advise and did and it worked

Comment: Great. If my answer helped them you can accept it so that your question is marked as answered. That will help other people searching with a similar problem